# What is the best way of repeating the iteration of for loop in C++?

Tags: c++

I wonder what is the best way of repeating the iteration of `for` loop in c++. If `for` loop has this form

```
for(int i=0;i<some_value;i++)
```

The solution I practice for repeating the same iteration is just returning the `i` to the previous value. It usually takes place after the `if` statement and at the end of the if-block I add `i--`. The problem with this is you always want to change parameters that you question in the `if` statement because you would end up with an infinite loop. So is there any better way of repeating the same iteration?

And I would like to extend the question to `for` loop in this form

```
for(int j : some_other_value)
```

How do you repeat the same iteration with this kind of `for` loop?

Comment: That's not a foreach loop. It's a range based for loop. You can't repeat the same iteration in a range based for loop.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Thanks I edited my question.

Comment: Reusing `int i` and `some_value` in your examples when they mean completely different things in those contexts is quite confusing.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I don't see what's wrong with colloquially referring to range-based for as "a foreach loop". That's exactly what it is.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Yeah, thanks for the insight. I edited that out.

Comment: `for (int i ....) { work(i); if (repeat) { work(i); } }`. Or even `for (int i...) { again: work(i); if (repeat) goto again; }`!

Comment: @KamilCuk I understand that `goto` is not good practice in c++. Am I wrong?

Comment: You're right. `goto` is a very advanced technique that should be used only when you know *exactly* why it's being used.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings You will find less helpful documentation searching for "foreach loop" and it could be confused with `std::foreach`. It could mean that OP doesn't know the correct name.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Knowing the standard term is definitely valuable, but "that's not a foreach loop" seems like an overstatement, is all.

Answer (score 2):

**You don't.**

If you need tighter control over your loop than simply forward-iterating over a sequence, ranged-based `for` is the wrong tool for the job.

Go back to an index-based loop instead.

Comment: @cigien So did I but then I realised the OP _also_ used `int i` for their element name in the range-based for example, so best avoid ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and is my practice of `i--` inside the first kind of loop good or I could use the better one?

Comment: @DaniloIvanovic I'm not wild about it, tbh - I'd prefer to take `i++` out of the loop intro and instead have it as a statement (conditionally executed) in the body. Some will say that's an easy way to get an accidental infinite loop, but tbh I don't think it's any worse than playing with the index in "strange" ways.